# Windows NTFS Permissions replacing child objects bulk

Tags: windows, permissions, ntfs

I have about 300 home user folders in a homes share. Each user has modify permissions to their own folder. They are connected to the folder via Active Directory with the \filerserver\homes$\%username% variable.

Each user has modify permissions on their home folder but when I merged their old folders into this one, if they had sub-folders in their home folder, the sub-folders did not inherit the parent NTFS permissions. Therefore, I need to go into each users folder security and click "Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object".

Is there a way to bulk apply this but keeping each user with modify permissions to their respectable folders but to also apply to subfolders?

Comment: perhaps modify script I posted in [this answer][1] for your own needs


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/360608/re-give-users-ownership-of-their-mapped-home-folders-via-powershell/360871#360871

Comment: How did you `"merge"` the folders? If you did a move (cut/paste) operation from the same volume, that's why. If you did a copy operation, or move from a different volume and it still did this, then you have inheritance set up wrong.

Comment: @MDMarra I did a move from the same volume :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, if you can have downtime, is to just do a copy instead of a move like you did. You might have to restore from backup and give it another go.

If you can't do that, you can use get-acl and set-acl in PowerShell to recursively apply permissions to a folder structure.

Comment: I was unaware of moving not inheriting permissions from the parent. At least I know where I went wrong now. I'm going to give that Jordan W.'s script a try since the restore from backup isn't going to work for us at this point. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, what I can do is delete the old homes share. Then I just re-create the homes share as an empty directory, go into active directory and mass connect everyone to the new homes share which will automatically add their user folder to the homes share and their user to the file security. Then I'll do a copy merge instead of a move merge. This should fix the issue, right?